# How to get valid binary path for cppcheck?

Tags: cppcheck

I am trying to install cppcheclipse from this website:

http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/cppcheclipse/wiki/Installation

I have followed the instructions there, however, when trying to configure it, it says the there is no valid binary path.

My question is how to get valid binary path?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have installed Cppcheck.. if you haven't then do it.

To find where cppcheck is installed on Linux:

```
which cppcheck
```

On Windows the path is something like:

```
c:\program files (x86)\cppcheck\cppcheck.exe
```

Comment: What if I am using mac?

Comment: I am using lunix but could not find it at all please tell me where I can point this out

Answer (score 0):

You need to first download the cppcheck itself and then install it. On Linux it seems to require compilation - which I can't get to work on my Ubuntu at least.

EDIT: Got the cppcheck now via apt-get but it's rather old version 1.27. and Eclipse gives me an error with it.. It seems I would need at least 1.48. version of cppcheck to get it working..
Flawfinder, splint, rats are giving me on CL better results though so I'm not sure if the cppcheck is worth the trouble of getting it set-up.. of course it could be that 1.68 is better..